# Configure two range axis in jFreeChart histogram

Tags: java, histogram, jfreechart

I have two series in a jFreeChart histogram. One is normally smaller then the other and we'd like to scale the smaller so it is similar to the larger series and I wanted to verify that it is possible to do this with jFreeChart's usual API and two separate range axis, presumably one on the right and the other on the left.

[image]

Comment: See the dual axis demos in the [gallery of samples](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jfreechart/info) and these [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bjfreechart%5d%20mapDatasetToRangeAxis) mentioning `mapDatasetToRangeAxis()`.

Comment: @trashgod Thank you that was exactly what i needed.

Comment: @trashgod As a sanity check can you confirm that there is no way to use two axises with a single dataset?

Comment: I haven't seen a counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official examples were quite helpful. Here is my solution based on them much thanks to trashgod's suggestion.

[image]

```
public void generateChart(List<FmsData> data, Valve valve) {

    HistogramDataset aggDs = createAggDataset(data);
    chart = createChart(aggDs, valve.getNumber());

    HistogramDataset valveDs = createValveDataset(data,valve.getNumber());
    XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();

    // configure the second dataset
    plot.setDataset(0, aggDs);
    plot.setDataset(1, valveDs);
    plot.setRangeAxisLocation(0, AxisLocation.BOTTOM_OR_LEFT);
    plot.setRangeAxisLocation(1, AxisLocation.BOTTOM_OR_RIGHT);
    plot.mapDatasetToRangeAxis(0, 0);
    plot.mapDatasetToRangeAxis(1, 1);

    NumberAxis valveRangeAxis = new NumberAxis();
    plot.setRangeAxis(1, valveRangeAxis);

    XYBarRenderer renderer2 = new XYBarRenderer();
    plot.setRenderer(1, renderer2);
    plot.setDatasetRenderingOrder(DatasetRenderingOrder.FORWARD);
    renderer2.setDrawBarOutline(false);
    // flat bars look best...
    renderer2.setBarPainter(new StandardXYBarPainter());
    renderer2.setShadowVisible(false);
    // end config second dataset
```